# How does one append something like "?x=123" to an NSURL?

Tags: ios

I have an NSURL of the form

```
"http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/"
```

and I want to append to it so the final url is like this

```
"http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/?x=123".
```

But if I do this

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/?"];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"x=123"];
```

Then the result is

```
http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/x=123?
```

(its the same result if URLByAppendingPathExtension is used).

But if I do this

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/?"];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"x=123"];
```

Then the result is

```
http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/%3Fx=123
```

(also the same result if URLByAppendingPathExtension is used).

Neither of which is what I am after. How do I get a final result of "http://abc.def.com:1234/stuff/?x=123" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest answer here is to create a new URL using the old one as the base URL.

```
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"?x=123" relativeToURL:url]
```

Here is a unit test that checks the logic

```
- (void)testCreatingQueryURLfromBaseURL
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com/bar/baz"];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"?x=1&y=2&z=3" relativeToURL:url];

    STAssertEqualObjects([url absoluteString], @"http://foo.com/bar/baz?x=1&y=2&z=3", nil);
}
```

Comment: When I am  trying above shown method My url is not coming proper it appears inverted like "?x=1&y=2&z=3 http://foo.com/bar/baz" please provide some solution If you have for this.
Thanks

Comment: @jalakpatel `url.description` returns `?x=1&y=2&z=3 -- http://foo.com/bar/baz`, so `NSLog(@"URL: %@", url)` will put `"URL: ?x=1&y=2&z=3 -- http://foo.com/bar/baz"` into the debugger. If you want to display the full URL, use `url.absoluteString`. For example, `NSLog(@"URL: %@", url.absoluteString)` will put `"URL: http://foo.com/bar/baz?x=1&y=2&z=3"` into the debugger.

Comment: @jalakpatel NOTE: `url.description` is for display only. Passing `url` to any method which takes a URL will go to the correct location.

Answer (score 5):

Create your actual `NSURL` object last, from an `NSString` that you build up as needed:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.site.com/";
if (some condition)
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"?x=123"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: The problem with this approach (that `URLByAppendingPathComponent` is supposed to resolve) is that if your base url doesn't have a trailing slash, you'll get a mangled url as the result unless you explicitly check for it. Seems like a no-win scenario, really.